# Karate Gatling: Changes to feature file aren't picked up

Tags: karate

I'm attempting to build a series of gatling tests triggering karate scenarios. Changes I'm making to the feature file are only occasionally picked up by Gatling.  For example, in the feature file code below, the first four items are run (including the commented out 'relationships' line):

```
Feature: This feature attempts to load the main tabs in sequence for the purposes of performance testing via gatling

    Background: Create the investigation and job first
      # Get api url from karate-config.js
      * url baseUrl
      # This configures the http headers to use admin user for running the tests
      * callonce read('classpath:common/headers/admin-headers.feature')

      * def investigaitonId = 150
      * def jobId = 51


  Scenario: Twitter investigation with 1 selector
    Given path 'investigations', investigaitonId
    When method get
    Then status 200

    Given path 'jobs', jobId
    When method get
    Then status 200

    Given path 'investigations', investigaitonId, 'actors'
    When method get
    Then status 200

    #Given path 'investigations', investigaitonId, 'relationships'
    #When method get
    #Then status 200

    Given path 'investigations', investigaitonId, 'entities'
    When method get
    Then status 200

    Given path 'investigations', investigaitonId, 'events'
    When method get
    Then status 200

    Given path 'investigations', investigaitonId, 'activities'
    When method get
    Then status 200

    Given path 'investigations', investigaitonId, 'activities-media'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

The rest aren't.  See attached screen of run results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyhha.png)

POM for reference to the versions:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <karate.version>0.9.4</karate.version>
        <junit5.version>5.5.1</junit5.version>
        <masterthought.version>4.9.0</masterthought.version>
        <gatling.plugin.version>3.0.2</gatling.plugin.version>
        <gatling.charts.version>3.2.1</gatling.charts.version>
        <scala.version>2.15.2</scala.version>
    </properties>
```

I suspect something like a compile file not refreshing or recompiling whenever a change is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved using the following command:

```
mvn clean test-compile gatling:test
```

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have something missing in your `pom.xml`. Please compare your setup with this project: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/gatling

If the `*.feature` files are not copied to the `target/test-classes` folder automatically - you will face this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I found the issue was resolved with the command: mvn clean test-compile gatling:test

Comment: @Puti yep. leaving `clean` out can be faster when in dev mode

Comment: @Puti regarding this comment `The process outline in the submit issue link is too cumbersome` - at the very least, you can point to a live site and provide 2-3 lines of script. and this process is not cumbersome: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test - I leave it to you, if you feel Karate is worth improving, you can spend some time - else of course you are free to switch to some other framework